# compiler cannot find type ITable for dynamic Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

The following code does not work because it is not coming out as the proper type for a query.  Neither below version will work, the bottom one where I try to cast it as an ITable does not work because it states I a missing a reference.

I am trying to make my code loop through the tables found in the first query (working) and then the columns also found in that query so I can later update them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;


namespace funwithsql
{
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        UTILEntities context = new UTILEntities();

        var tables = from data in context.custtables
                     select new
                     {
                         col1 = data.TableName.ToString(),
                         col2 = data.columnname.ToString()
                     };

        var tableslist = tables.Select(s => new { col1 = s.col1, col2 = s.col2 }).ToList();



        foreach (var table in tableslist)
        {

            var intable = context.GetType().GetProperty(table.col1.ToString()).GetValue(context,null);
           var tline = from tdata in context.GetType().GetProperty(table.col1.ToString()).GetValue(context, null)
            select tdata;


        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by `it does not work`? Are you getting error? What does this code do? What functionality or feature you are trying to implement by this code? Which line of code is giving you error ?

Comment: The line where I am attempted the get table I am getting this error Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'object'.  'Select' not found.

Comment: I assume the problem is because I am casting it to the proper type which I would assume to be ITable, but if I attempt that it states:  var tline = from tdata in (ITable)context.GetType().GetProperty(table.col1.ToString()).GetValue(context, null)    The type or namespace 'ITable' could not be found are you missing a reference.

Comment: It look like you are looking the table name as a property in the context, The `GetValue` function will return an object, you should cast it to the IQueryable of type or IEnumerable of type object to perform queries againts it. Can you be more clear in what error or issue are you facing.

Comment: If this is the issue, you must add the reference of the library that contain the information and metadata of `ITable`

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure which library I'm missing.  So far as I can tell it should be in Linq, which is included, but it still isn't apparently finding the reference.